# Texture atlas either not found or resource missing images used

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I've just started using a texture atlas. It worked just fine up until I attempted to change the name from one with an uppercase letter to the same with a  lowercase letter. Since then Xcode has been unable to find my atlases. Either that or when it can it loads the missing resource image rather than the one it should use.

I've deleted derived data, restarted Xcode and the Mac. Deleted and recreated the atlas folders in Xcode. Nothing seems to make a difference thus far.

Here's the code where I load the assets, just in case I've messed something up in it.

```
NSMutableArray *animationFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
SKTextureAtlas *animationAtlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"animationImages"];

for (int i = 1; i < animationAtlas.textureNames.count; i++) {
    NSString *texture = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"animationImage%02d", i];
    [animationFrames addObject:[animationAtlas textureNamed:texture]];
}

SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[animationFrames firstObject]];
```

Comment: I'm marginally closer to what's actually happening now. When I retrieve the texture names from the animationAtlas array, it gives me the wrong name for the first image on the sequence. Consequently it's trying to load the wrong file which is why its not found. I've deleted the derived data and also loaded the app onto another device which it wasn't even on before, but it's still giving me the wrong names. Anything else I can clear out?

Comment: So now it's looking for the right files, but not finding them.

Answer (score 1):

If you just changed the case of the name, it's probably not a texture atlas problem. Depending on how you renamed the resource, the Xcode name likely differs from the name on disk. If you added them as references to the project and not copied actual images, this is likely the issue. If they were copied (as in the group is backed by a folder on disk), it's likely a naming typo somewhere. You said it's still loading resources that are not there, which points to a dirty cache copy - make totally sure you uninstall the app from the device if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Note that on iOS the file system is case sensitive. You can actually have two files with the same name differing only in case, for example:

```
animationImages.png
animationimages.png
```

So if you changed the case of a filename in your project, you have to change the corresponding code that loads this file **even if the rename only changed the file's casing**.

Also when replacing files, be sure to delete the app from the device and perform a **Project -> Clean**. Xcode only adds files to the bundle, it will never remove them, so your code may still inadvertently access the old file even though it's no longer in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can't have identically named textures -- even if they're in separate atlases. My project had, for example, Atlas1 -> "someImage" and Atlas2 -> "someImage".

When I renamed all the textures inside the second sprite atlas, it was found/loaded as desired

Another option if you have same texture names for each atlas, for example "idle_00", click on the atlas folder in assets, and on the attribute inspector, click the tick mark in "provides namespace", it will add atlas_name/texture_name for the textures, you can still call the texture directly as texture_name when you try to access texture from code

```
let atlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "atlas_name")
```

let texture = atlas.textureNamed("texture_name")